# Solve for $x$ without using Lambert's $W$-Function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would you solve $x=e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x$ without using Lambert $W$-Function? WolframAlpha uses $W$, but I want to solve without using $W$.

Thanks

Comment: You have used both upper case $X$ and lower case $x$. Do these represent the same, or are they different?

Comment: Sorry they are the same. I will edit the main post

Comment: I want so solve $x^2=2$ without square-root

Comment: @Fabian XD hey, you've always got fractional powers if that's your cup of tea!! That being a joke though, it has always fascinated me that, with tetration, the Super-Root and Super-Fractional Powers are not the same. Easy proof, but fascinating as to what breaks down. That all being said,  nice one XD

Answer (score 3):

With the substitution $y=\frac{1}{x}$ the equation becomes $\,y\,e^y=1\,$ whose solution is by definition the [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant) $\,\Omega\,$. Therefore $y=\Omega$ so $x=\frac{1}{\Omega}$.

While $\Omega$ is usually calculated in terms of [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as $\Omega=W(1)$, expressions exist for $\Omega$ which don't use the $W$ function. One such can be derived from Victor Adamchik's identity:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(e^t - t)^2+\pi^2} = \frac{1}{1 + \Omega}$$

which gives:

$$x = \frac{1}{\Omega} = \frac{1}{1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{(e^t - t)^2+\pi^2}} - 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer? You can't. Lambert's $W$ Function is not expressible in terms of elementary functions, which include addition, multiplication, division, subtraction, exponentiation, logarithms, and sinusoidal functions. Why is this so? I recommend studying Differential Galois Theory when you have a chance! I know I've seen somewhat layman introductions into the theory if you look around this site!